# Separating the variables

Tags: calculus

If $\frac{dv}{dt} = g-3kv$, what does $v$ tend to as $t$ tends to infinity?

I have tried integrating in two different ways: one way I get an equation with $e^t$ and the other I get an equation with $e^{-t}$.

Answer (score 1):

First rewrite the equation as 
$$ \frac{dv}{g-3kv} = dt.$$
Integrate and combine the constants to get
$$ \frac{1}{-3k}ln(g-3kv)= t + C.$$
Multiply both sides by $-3k$ and raise each side to get
$$ g-3kv = e^{-3kt+C}.$$
Now we're in a position to say what happens as t approaches $\infty$. When t approaches $\infty$, the quantity $-3kt+C$ approaches $-\infty$. This means on the right side of the equation we have $e^{-\infty}$, which is zero. Once you realize this you can solve directly for v and get $v=\frac{-g}{3k}$.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to prefer not to explicitly separate differentials in solving DEs, so here are two calculations for this problem that avoid doing so. First there is the way with an integrating factor:

$$v'(t)+3kv(t)=g \\
v'(t)e^{3kt}+3ke^{3kt}v(t)=e^{3kt}g \\
\frac{d}{dt} \left ( v(t) e^{3kt} \right ) = e^{3kt} g \\
\int_0^t \frac{d}{ds} \left ( v(s) e^{3ks} \right ) ds = \int_0^t e^{3ks} g ds.$$

The rest is basic calculus and algebra.

The second is to divide both sides by the right side:

$$\frac{v'(t)}{g-3kv(t)}=1 \\
\int_0^t \frac{v'(s)}{g-3kv(s)} ds =\int_0^t ds = t \\
\int_{v(0)}^{v(t)} \frac{1}{g-3kv} dv = t$$

where in the last step I used a substitution. Now again you just have some calculus and algebra to do.